# how to get the first non NULL value in a MAP?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

i have an STL map ;
i would like to get the first non NULL value in the map; 
is there an efficient/quick way to do that?

Comment: When you say "first", do you mean first in insertion order? first in key order? Or just any single non-NULL element?

Comment: @Eran: For _ordered_ STL containers, it's generally understood that "the order" refers to the one specified by the predicate (i.e. `std::less<T>` unless specified otherwise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsNotNull(const pair<const int, int>& i)
{
        return i.second != 0;
}

int main() {

        map<int, int> m;
        m[0] = 0;
        m[1] = 1;
        map<int, int>::const_iterator it = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), IsNotNull);
        cout << it->second << endl;
        return 0;

}
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/W0Iso)

Comment: You can skip the `IsNotNull` predicate using `boost::bind`, e.g. `map<int, int>::const_iterator it = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), boost::bind(&pair<const int, int>::second, _1));`

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing quicker than just looping through and finding what you're looking for

```
for (map<X,Y>::const_iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
{
  if (i->second != NULL)
  {
    // do something with first non-NULL value
    break;
  }
}
```